# can I check whether my android device is booted in safe mode or not programmatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, safe-mode

I am a new learner for android, I want to develop an API. I want to check whether my android device is booted in safe mode or not programmatically, is there any parameter? **I checked the Settings.System parameters** but I didn't find anything?. I a using Visual studio for development and android marshmallow for testing.

Comment: i saw this method isSafeMode() in PackageManager can u give a try?

Comment: thanks, Lingeshwaran got it...!

Comment: post your code it might help to someone in future.